# IndexOutOfBoundException when creating an Array from a List

Tags: java

I have this method that returns a `List` of usernames, and for some reason it is throwing an `indexOutOfBoundException`.

```
public  String [] getUsernames(){
    String[] usernames = new String [friendRequests.size()];
    int i = 1;
    for (FriendRequest  friendRequest:  this.friendRequests){
        usernames[i]= friendRequest.getUsername();
        i++;
    }
    return usernames;
}
```

Comment: What is it doing? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: and what is `friend_requests` ?

Comment: i think you should use a normal for- loop for it...

Comment: This is java, `get_usernames` should be `getUsernames`. `Single_FR` should be `SingleFR` (although you may just want to rename this to `FriendRequest`. and `friend_requests` should be `friendRequests`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

array index starts from `0`

and you started from `1`, so it would lead to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Answer (score 5):

Use this.
There arrays have index started from zero.
There will be ArrayIndexOutOfBound

```
public  String [] getUsernames(){
    String[] usernames = new String [this.friendRequests.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (FriendRequest  fr:  this.friendRequests){
        usernames[i] = fr.getUsername();
        i++;
    }

    return usernames;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the last element.

Change the statement

`i = 1`

into

`i = 0`;

and the issue should be fixed. Array indices start from `0`, not from `1`.